Two SDEs that share a Brownian motion
I have the system
\begin{align}
dX_t & = \beta(\alpha - X_t)dt + Y_t dt + dB^1_t + dB^2_t \newline
dY_t & = \beta(\alpha - Y_t)dt + X_t dt + dB^2_t + dB^3_t
\end{align}
Now, I am creating a scheme where I can, for example, solve for $X_t$, and then keep this value fixed in the SDE for $Y_t$, solve for $Y_t$ and then combine the solutions in some way.
What bothers me is the shared Brownian motions. I know that $dB^1_t + dB^2_t$ is another Brownian motion, so if I fix $Y_t = y$, I can analytically solve for $X_{t + \Delta t}$, because when $Y_t = y$ is fixed, the SDE is an Ornstein--Uhlenbeck process. But then, when I fix $X_{t + \Delta t}$, and I want to solve for $Y_{t + \Delta t}$ I have in some way implicitly simulated $dB^2_t$ so there will be some correlation. I wouldn't be able to simply solve it like an Orstein--Uhlenbeck process. Or could I?

Why isn't the Euler-Maruyama or Milstein scheme sufficient for simulating the system $(X,Y)$? I'm a little confused because the tags say 'numerical-methods' and 'simulation' but you talk about analytically solving for $X_{t+\Delta t}$ etc. If your goal is just simulation, EM or Milstein should work fine here.
(Pedantic comment: $B_t^1+B_t^2$ is equal in distribution to $\sqrt{t} Z^1 +\sqrt{t} Z^2$ which is equal in distribution to a $\mathcal{N}(0, 2t)$ RV, assuming independence. So the sum is not a standard Brownian motion.)

if that shared $B^2_t$ worries you, you can use $X_t$ and $Y_t-X_t$ instead of $X_t$ and $Y_t$

@NapD.Lover Sorry, maybe it's a misunderstanding. I would call that exact simulation. I would like to use the property that OU can be simulated exactly.

@user8268 Thanks! What if the drift and diffusion functions are a bit more complicated? For example if the diffusion function depends on the state (i.e. Cox--Ingersoll--Ross). Is there a way to still use $X_t$ and $Y_t$?

The hint by @user8268 is brilliant. I luv it when OP immediately raises the bar a bit. Hint for that:  work in matrix/vector notation and solve the system numerically. Standard book: Kloeden & Platen.

I like the hint, but what happens then is that I sample from the exact transition density for $X$, but the $Y_t - X_t$ will still contain $B^1_t$,  which is shared again.
